# Loopback get filtered result in the same order

Tags: loopbackjs

I have two loopback model like

```
Model1
{
   "id":"",
   "name":"",
   "model2Ids":[]
}
```

This model has an array of model 2 ids using the referencesMany relation.
I want to query Model from the remote method of model 1.
My remote method is as follows

```
Model1.customRemoteMethod = function(id, cb) {
    var Model2 = Model1.app.models.model2;
    Model1.findById(id, function(model1Error, model1Obj) {
        if (model1Error) cb(model1Error);
        if (model1Error.model2Ids) {
            var model2Filter = {
            'where': {
                'id': {'inq': model1Obj.model2Ids}
                }
             };
            Model1.find(model2Filter, function(model2Error, model2s) {
                if (model2Error) cb(model2Error);
                cb(null, Object.assign({}, JSON.parse(JSON.stringify((channelMapObj))), {
                    model2s: model2s
                }));
             });
        }
    })
})
```

I want the models that are returned(that is the filtered results) to be in the same array as that of my ids in Model1.Is there a way to do it.?

For example if I query using id 2,1,3.
Then the results should be the same order and not 1,2,3(as found in model 2).

The only solution that I have would be to loop over the id, and the use findById to get all results in same order.

Comment: Or, once you have the result 1,2,3 - you can sort them as per original query. Won't that be good enough?

Because in loopback there no way you can ensure the sequence of the result set. Most likely it 'll be as per the id column (default sort)